# tox run python command in sudo

Tags: python, tox

When I try to run a test command using `sudo python ...`, tox uses the system Python instead of the tox-specified version. How can I run commands in sudo using tox?

```
commands =
    sudo python -m pytest  # always runs system python!
```

Answer (score 1):

`python` in Tox commands will only be replaced if it is a command. Technically, `sudo python ...` will run the system command `sudo` and pass it "python" as the first argument.

Tox provides a number of [substitutions](https://testrun.org/tox/latest/config.html#globally-available-substitutions) that allow for a lot of flexibility. In your case, you'll want something like

```
commands =
    sudo {envpython} -m pytest  # always uses the right python :)
```